# Determine if the points are within the 3D triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have the points $p=(1,1,1)$, $q=(1,2,3)$ and $r=(-1,0,-1)$. These points make a triangle.I have another 3 points $s=(1,5,4)$, $t=(3,5,9)$ and $u=(\frac13,\frac56,0)$. How to determine if these 3 points are in triangle $PQR$? 
I looked at a few solutions but did not understand and the post too old so the people wont reply to my questions. Can someone give me a step by step guide how to solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

The hint:

Take a point $K=xP+yQ+zR$, where $x\geq0,$ $y\geq0$, $z\geq0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

Thus, $K$ is placed inside the $\Delta PQR$.

Can you end it now?

I got the $S$ and $U$ are not placed even in the plane $PQR$.

Comment: but how to find x,y,and z

Comment: Just solve the system.

Comment: u mean simultaneous equation?

Comment: $(3,5,9)=x(1,1,1)+y(1,2,3)+z(-1,0,-1).$